# going to the previous block of code in while loop

Tags: ruby

I have 2-questions for the user to enter the same value. Example:

```
Q1 - enter value
Q2 - re-enter value
```

If user enters NIL value then "Q1" should be prompted again which is working fine in my code. But user enters NIL for "Q2" then again "Q1" needs to be prompted followed by "Q2". But in my code "Q2" is prompting again. Can somebody help me with the logic here.

Here is my peice of code:

```
 def getPrompt(input)
         p1 = ""
         p2 = ""

         while 1
             puts "Entered getInput"

              while "#{p1}" == ""
                     p1 = ask("Enter #{input}: ") do |ch|
                          ch.echo = true
                     end

                     if "#{p1}" == ""
                          print "#{ch} cannot be empty string.\n".red
                      end

                end

                while "#{p2}" == ""
                      p2 = ask("Re-enter #{p1}: ") do |ch|
                           ch.readline = true
                       end

                       if "#{p2}" == ""
                           print "#{p1} cannot be empty string.\n".red
                       end
                 end

                 if "#{p1}".casecmp("#{p2}") == 0
                     break
                 else
                     print "#{val} mis-match\n".red
                 end

           end

                return "#{p1}"

         end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to place the second loop inside the first one.

But you really don't need all those loops. There are also other issues with your code, for example you don't need to interpolate `p1` to a string via `"#{p1}"`, it is already a string.

However, a first solution could be something like this:

```
def getPrompt(input)
  p1 = ""
  p2 = ""

  while p1 == "" or p1 != p2
    p1 = ask("Enter #{input}: ")

    if p1 == ""
      puts "#{input} cannot be empty string."
    else
      p2 = ask("Re-enter #{input}: ")

      if p2 == ""
        puts "#{input} cannot be empty string."
      elsif p1 != p2
        puts "mis-match"
      end
    end
  end

  return p1
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for talking about interpolating `p1`. I tried to edit my method with your logic and that works.